# Side by side plots using scatterplot from car package

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot, r-car

Is there some reason you cannot lay two scatterplot (from car package) figures side by side?

```
library(car)

str(UN)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
scatterplot(infant.mortality~gdp,data=UN,
            xlab="GDP per capita",
            ylab="Infant Morality Rate (per 1000 births)",
            main="(a)",
            boxplot=FALSE)
scatterplot(infant.mortality~gdp,data=UN,
            xlab="GDP per capita",
            ylab="Infant Morality Rate (per 1000 births)",
            main="(b)",
            log='xy',
            boxplot=FALSE,id.n=4)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

The above code produces both images, but not as one image side by side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scatterplot` function overrides your `par()` configuration, as it calls internally the `layout()` function to display the scatterplot along with the marginal boxplots.

This question was already answered by John Fox, the creator of that function. You can see [his answer at the R-help mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-February/229304.html).

Or, if you do not trust him, you can just [have a look at the source code](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/%2acheckout%2a/pkg/R/scatterplot.R?revision=311&root=car) and search for `layout`. You will find the `if - else if - else if - else` sentence in which the `layout()` function is called in all cases.

Comment: His answer: "scatterplot() [...] can't be used with par("mfrow")"